# Manage option value of attribute option disappears

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, attributes, catalog, attribute-options

I have an attribute named as Product_type.
**Catalog > Manage attributes > Attribute Name(Product_type) > 
Manage Labels/Options > 
Manage Options (values of your attribute)**
When I choose **Use In Layered Navigation to Filterable(with results)** in frontend properties,then
in Manage Options (values of your attribute) value of some attributes disappears.Whenever I click on save and continue edit different values disappears each time.I have almost 600 values as attribute option.[image]  [image] [image]
PFA